# What if mitmproxy7 has no change_upstream_proxy_server?

Tags: mitmproxy

What if mitmproxy7 has no change_upstream_proxy_server? what to replace?

```
#  mitmproxy.py
class Proxy:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def request(self, flow):
        if 'stackoverflow.com' in flow.request.url:
            # ctx.log.info(flow.request.url)
            proxy = ("127.0.0.1", 8081)
        else:
            proxy = ("127.0.0.1", 8082)

        if flow.live:
            flow.live.change_upstream_proxy_server(proxy)
```

test2

```
#  mitmproxy.py
class Proxy:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def request(self, flow):
        if 'stackoverflow.com' in flow.request.url:
            # ctx.log.info(flow.request.url)
            proxy = ("127.0.0.1", 8081)
            flow.live.change_upstream_proxy_server(proxy)
        else:
            proxy = ("127.0.0.1", 8082)
        flow.live.change_upstream_proxy_server(proxy)
```

```
mitmweb.exe  --mode upstream:http://127.0.0.1:8080/ -s mitmproxy.py
```

errinfo

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'change_upstream_proxy_server'

Comment: Just look into the provided example script: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/main/examples/contrib/change_upstream_proxy.py